# SharePoint how to add button to Navbar in List Template?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am trying to integrate the SharePoint extension in Teams and can't find a solution, to add a Label, Button or other type of Link to the NavBar.
The list i used was a generated with a template.
[image: NavBar i am talking about]

I tried to connect the different types of lists, with a homepage which is automatically generated in SharePoint.
After i redesigned the homepage, added the different links in a hero and connected the SharePoint site to Teams, i saw that that after clicking the link which led me to the list i could not go back to the homepage anymore.

[image: Teams Menu]

The only way to access the homepage again was via dropdown on IT-Tickets and reload tab or closing it entirely.
The question is, how can i add an Element, after Open in SharePoint which links me back to the homepage ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a link to SharePoint list command bar using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

You have to develop a SPFx ListView Command Set extension to add a link or button to SharePoint list command bar:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)